# Selenium Webdriver Recognized as Malware on Windows (Python)

Tags: python, windows, selenium, webdriver, malware

I wrote a program in Python that needs to perform tasks on the browser with Selenium. I build a one-file exe and tried to run it on my Windows machine, yet Windows seems to recognize it as some malware and immediately removes it. Is this a thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of malware that is created in python and compiled into exe files, so a lot of anti-virus scanners tend to falsely flag these as malware unfortunately. I think the easiest thing to do it just add your development folder to the list of safe folders in Windows defender.

Comment: ok, understand, thanks.